# Java Overriding abstract class method with an interface as param

Tags: java, oop

I have this abstract class:

```
public abstract class Foo{
   //some attributes

   public Foo(params){}

   public abstract SomeInterface search(Long id);
   public abstract boolean insert(SomeInterface param);
}
```

I have the following class:

```
public class InterfaceImplementation implements SomeInterface {
  //Some code here
}
```

Then I create an instance of Foo:

```
public class Bar extends Foo{

  public Foo(params){
    super(params);
  }

  @Override
  public InterfaceImplementation search(Long id){
    // some code here
  }
  // The above code compiles

  @Override
  public boolean insert(InterfaceImplementation param){
    // some code specific to the InterfaceImplementation here
  }
  // This function does not compile/
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong and how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why are you using "InterfaceImplementation" rather than "SomeInterface" in `Bar`? It should not care which implementation, just that it is a `SomeInterface`.

Comment: Because I need to do some code specific to that implementation. I tried with abstract class as well with the same result.
The insert action would insert the object to the database, on which I need to set parameters according to that object's parameters. Maybe I'm taking a wrong approach to the problem?

Comment: Do you really need to allow a Bar to be treated as a `Foo`, with `Foo` defined in terms of the interface, rather than the actual class?

Comment: I've been doing it that way but I didn't feel quite comfortable with it. I'll change everything to generics just as @rgettman recommended

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class `Bar` doesn't override `insert`, because the parameter types must match exactly.  This is because your implementation takes an `InterfaceImplementation`, not a `SomeInterface`.

What you can do to get this to compile:

1. Take a `SomeInterface` as a parameter in `Bar`'s `insert` method, because any subclass should be able to process any implementation of `SomeInterface`, as specified by `Foo`.

OR

2. Introduce generics in `SomeInterface` to specify what should be the parameter type.

   ```
   public abstract class Foo<T extends SomeInterface>{
   ```

and

```
public abstract boolean insert(T param);
```

Then you can specify what `T` is in the subclass:

```
public class Bar extends Foo<InterfaceImplementation>{
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean insert(InterfaceImplementation param){
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say I had

```
Foo foo = new Bar();
```

and tried to do

```
foo.insert(new OtherInterfaceImpl());
```

I would be allowed to do this because `Foo#insert` accepts a `SomeInterface` and `OtherInterfaceImpl` implements `SomeInterface`.

However, `Bar`'s implementation of `insert` could not accept a `OtherInterfaceImpl` since you specifically said so with this declaration

```
 public boolean insert(InterfaceImplementation param){
```

This would break type safety and is therefore not allowed.

You can use generics as [rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28487474/438154) has shown.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *restrict* parameters when implememting an superclass method.

You *can* restrict the output to subtypes.

Consider the method

```
Number sum(Number a, Number b);
```

which may be used with arbitrary numbers, e.g.

```
Number out = sum(Double.valueOf(1.23), Integer.valueOf(7));
```

and the "candidates"

```
Double sum(Number a, Number b) {
  return a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue()
}
```

vs.

```
Number sum(Integer a, Double b) {
  return (Byte) (a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue());
}
```

Which of the two implements above API correctly?